# Consume ASP WebAPI from ActionResult in different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to consume WebAPI service from `ActionResult` in another controller?
Basicaly i have a controller that returns the data.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    public MyData Get()
    {
      //returns the data
    }

}
```

and i want to consume this data from

```
public class MyConsumeController: Controller
{

    public ActionResult MyConsumeAction()
    {
       var something = //Call Get inside MyApiController 
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Note: I know how to consume it using HttpClient (different project) or jquery (from views).

Comment: Are the controllers in the same app? If yes, why don't you just extract out the `MyData Get()` to a separate class and use it from both places?

Comment: It's a webapi service. To invoke the Get() you go to  /api/MyApiController .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [client API](http://www.johnnycode.com/blog/2012/02/23/consuming-your-own-asp-net-web-api-rest-service/) - the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. And here's [another sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee).

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answere and providing the link to sample but i know how to use HttpClient. I wrote it in the note ("I know how to consume it using HttpClient"), i was thinking if there is any other way i should know? If this is the best approach i'll accept your answer.

Comment: That's the best way. You could use the standard WebClient but you will have to manually parse the JSON and stuff. All those things are built in the new HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to check with someone to confirm the approach i'm using.

Comment: @plurby, if application is same then use the in memory host.